# Как получить текущий адрес страницы и сократить её

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Есть скрипт, который добавляет куки

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var fav_cookie_name = $('#btfs-block').attr('data-favorites-uid');
var fav_cookie_value = window.location.href;
$('.fmb_icon-favorites-noactive').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.fmb_icon-favorites-active').show();
    $.cookie(fav_cookie_name, fav_cookie_value, { 
        expires: 365, 
        path: "/", 
        secure: true 
    });
});
});
```

Нужно чтобы название куки бралось из текущей страницы сайта и полностью сократиться до последнего слэша, пример: mysite.ru/city/name-shop , должно сократиться до name-shop . Помогите пожалуйста с решением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const paths = location.pathname.split('/');
let fav_cookie_value = paths[paths.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

```js
const href = 'http://mysite.ru/city/name-shop';

console.log(href.replace(/.+\//, ''));

console.log(href.slice(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

console.log(href.split('/').pop());
```